# Highcharts background image size option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to render charts on webpage. Now I found an issue if I use `min-width` and `max-width` CSS option on container div:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 960px; height:400px;"></div>
```

I added a background image with this method:

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        plotBackgroundImage: '/path/to/mybackgroundimage.png'
    }
};
```

This image has 960px width and 400px height and it shows well on desktops, but if I check it on mobile devices the image's apect ratio has gone and the image become distorted.

Is there a `backgroundSize:'cover'` or something like this to fix the image position and size on different screen widths?

Comment: Yes, you can use background-size: cover; check this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: @riteshmeher: no, I can't because the Highcahrts jQuery software create an SVG image to the charts, and the background image in SVG file is an `image` tag in fact.

Comment: Is it helpful? http://jsfiddle.net/wpuxawbs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the plotBackgroundImage parameter and set the backgroundColor as transparent. Then apply the background img in CSS (for the container).

CSS

```
#container {
   background:url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/skies.jpg) 0% 0%;
   background-size:cover;
}
```

chart:

```
chart: {
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
   type: 'line'
}
```

Example
- http://jsfiddle.net/4q7atyt9/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **rem** instead of **px**.

rem is called "root em" can change the size depend on the screen size.

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 20rem; max-width: 60rem; height:15rem;"></div>
```

**Note:**

10px = 0.625rem;
16px = 1rem;

Comment: not the rem or px is the really problem... the problem is the aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

in your css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:980px) {
  #container { 
  min-width: 20rem; //change the size
  max-width: 60rem; 
  height: 15rem;
 }
}
```